# Crashlytics:Upload a Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics

The Crashlytics say we need to download the Fabric Plugin on Android Studio and then register/upload the app by running it. I have few questions about the same topic.

- How to upload a Cordova (Ionic) based project to Crashlytics?
- How to use this [cordova-crashlytics](https://github.com/4sh-projects/cordova-crashlytics-plugin) plugin?

Any help is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without Android Studio and without "uploading your app/project" to Crashlytics and without having their Fabric plugin. I'm working on a Cordova app using the Cordova CLI tool with Cordova Android platform 3.7.2. I got Crashlytics working by usign this slightly updated Cordova plugin: https://github.com/smistry-toushay/cordova-crashlytics-plugin

First get your Crashlytics Secret and Key by visiting the "Organizations Page" in your Crashlytics dashboard. Select your org at: https://www.crashlytics.com/settings/organizations and click on the links for "API Key" and "Build Secret" right underneath the org's name to copy those values.

Then run this on a command line in your Cordova directory:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/smistry-toushay/cordova-crashlytics-plugin.git --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_SECRET=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API SECRET HERE --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API KEY HERE
```

That should then add your Cordova App to the Crashlytics dashboard and any subsequent crashes will show up there.

Comment: This is a newer Cordova plugin to use now: https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Since developing ionic uses text editors only, and not IDE, we don't really use the android studio. However, for this special case, where native should immerse We will need to force build our app from studio.

What you can do is to

1. add android platform to cordova app.
2. import app to Android studio (File, Import Project, yourapp/platform/android)
3. follow the instruction from  Crashlytics.
4. You can now proceed with your API keys and Build Secret.
5. on cli, follow the code to add the plugin "cordova plugin add cordova-..."
6. run the app on android studio.

Please let me know if this helps.
I was able to do this before, but I'll try to help you out everytime. 
Cheers!

Comment: Your instructions may be good, but I would not recommend starting your question with "What I did was...".  Instead recommend that the person try following the steps, and let them know why this might solve the problem.  That way you will be less likely to get voted down / flagged.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'll do that.  I just got my 50th reputation this week.

Comment: Great job, and congrats on your reputation.  :)